# Jaguards database configured incorrectly

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, debian, tomcat, login

After following the steps given in the [README](https://www-jaguards-com.translate.goog/downloads/README.txt?_x_tr_sl=fr&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=wapp) of the open source tool provided by [Jaguards](https://www.jaguards.com/main-courante/command-information-center/), I always get the "Database configured incorrectly" warning icon, and can't manage to login with the default credentials, or worse, a "checkDB error : com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details" popup.

Steps followed :

- Install a tomcat server, and load the war file
- Install a mysql server (also tried a mariadb server) and init the database with jaguards-4.0.sql
- Changed the database user's password in config file (user and db named "jaguards_gwt" so it matches with default config)

Database configuration : 8.0.31 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Tried on Ubuntu Server 22.04 and Debian, does not work on both.

Looking at the logs in /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
```

I managed to get rid of the warning by including the [latest connector](https://dbschema.com/jdbc-driver/MySql.html), but still cannot login.

Any idea ?

UPDATE

- Browser console gives the following : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
  0.js:1777 Uncaught zp
  0.js:2418 POST http://srvjaguards:8080/jaguards-4/gwtRequest 404"

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at dba since you will find there database legends ;)

Comment: @djdomi thanks for your answer. What do you mean by dba ? I cannot find the database legends... I am not familiar with such projects

Comment: djdomi is referring to the [dba.se] sister site, but IMO the question is off topic there. You will need however to provide your database configuration details to get an answer here.

Comment: Your MySQL server logs could also hold relevant information.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider nothing relevant in /var/log/mysql/error.log :/

And thanks for the dba exchange, didn't know this one exists ! I will edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINAL UPDATE

After giving a look at the logs in /opt/tomcat/logs, I solved the problems by upgrading/adding the dependencies :

- https://dbschema.com/jdbc-driver/MySql.html
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaxbapi22jar.htm

Comment: remember that you need to accept your answer if it is solved ;)

Comment: Yup I had a time limit and went to weekend. Thanks for the reminder :)